# Doing Groupby in Django ORMs

Tags: python, django

I have a simple table with the following values

```
 "uid": "some_uid",
 "name": "test1",
 "trig_time": 1234, #unix timestamp
 "notify_time": 1235  #unix timestamp
```

I have lot of tuples which may or may not have the same name. I intend to groupby results based on name and have the no of counts and the latest trig_time returned as result. For example ,for the following tuples

```
name,trig_time,notify_time
test1,1234,1235
test1,1236,1237
test2,1238,1239
```

expected result

```
name,count,latest_trig_time
test1,2,1236
test2,1,1238
```

I tried with the following query. I am not sure, what I am doing wrong.

```
queryset = Trig.objects.filter(uid=uid).annotate(count=Count('name')).order_by('name')
```

Based on the comments,
I am using Djangorestframework the following is my model

```
class Trig(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    trig_time = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    notify_time = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'uid', 'trig_time')
```

do I have to change my serializer code as well ? I executed the query in django shell and it worked fine. But in the server, I get the following error

> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
>   attribute or key on the `dict` instance.

The following is my serializer code

```
class TrigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trig
        fields = ('uid','name','trig_time','notify_time')
```

Comment: You should post the Django model code instead of the database representation - especially if you want an answer that uses the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregation with `values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values) to get there:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max

Trig.objects.filter(uid=uid).values('name')\
                    .annotate(count=Count('id'), latest_trig=Max(trig_time))\
                    .order_by()
```

(See the documentation for why that last empty `order_by()` is needed).

This will give you counts of each `name` item, and the latest `trig_time` for each group.